# How to update TreeTableView data?

Tags: java, javafx

I am writing app that measures time spent on tasks. I have TableTreeView that contains details of project and its tasks.

This is how it looks:[TableTreeViewImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDXWx.png)

What I want is to make duration`s column updating its values when task is running. Also project duration should be updated.

This is my model:

```
public abstract class SimpleTask{
    abstract Duration getDuration();
}

public class Task extends SimpleTask{
    Duration duration;

    @Override
    public Duration getDuration(){
        return duration;
    }

    public start(){
        //update duration value every second;
    }

}


public class Project extends SimpleTask{
    List<Task> tasks;

    @Override
    public Duration getDuration(){
        return tasks.stream()
                .map(Task::getDuration)
                .reduce(Duration.ZERO,Duration::plus);
        }
```

I have tried to bind duration column with method getDuration() but then TableTreeView needs to be refreshed to update values in this column.

```
durat.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<SimpleTask, Duration>, ObservableValue<Duration>>() {
          @Override
          public ObservableValue<Duration> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<GeneralTask, Duration> SimpleTaskDurationCellDataFeatures) {
              return new SimpleObjectProperty<Duration>(SimpleTaskDurationCellDataFeatures.getValue().getValue().getDuration());
          }
      });
```

How can I make duration column updating its values when task is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a `ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Duration>` to `SimpleTask` and use it instead of a new `SimpleObjectProperty` created by the `cellValueFactory`. otherwise you'd need to "manually trigger" update the table using `TableView.refresh` (available starting with javafx 8u60) every time a duration is modified:

```
public abstract class SimpleTask {

    public abstract Duration getDuration();

    public abstract ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Duration> durationProperty();
}

public class Task extends SimpleTask {

    private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Duration> duration = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>();

    @Override
    public Duration getDuration() {
        return duration.get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Duration> durationProperty() {
        return duration.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public void start() {
        //update duration value every second using this.duration.set(newDuration);
    }

}

public class Project extends SimpleTask {

    private final ObservableList<Task> tasks;

    private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Duration> duration;

    public Project() {
        this.duration = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>();
        this.tasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList(t -> new Observable[]{t.durationProperty()});
        this.duration.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(()
                -> tasks.stream()
                .map(Task::getDuration)
                .reduce(Duration.ZERO, Duration::plus),
                this.tasks));
    }

    @Override
    public Duration getDuration() {
        return duration.get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Duration> durationProperty() {
        return duration.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

}
```

```
durat.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<SimpleTask, Duration>, ObservableValue<Duration>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<Duration> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<SimpleTask, Duration> simpleTaskDurationCellDataFeatures) {
        return simpleTaskDurationCellDataFeatures.getValue().getValue().durationProperty();
    }
});
```

Note that you could reduce the code duplication by extracting all members except `start()` from `Task` to another abstract class, adding `protected` methods to access the property itself, not only it's readonly version and extending that class with `Project` too.